# Exclude hidden input value from search query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been looking for the solution of my problem, but I could not find one. I have a wordpress site in which I have two search forms. The search forms are displaying according to the page parameter. Both search forms have hidden input field with different values. So both forms go to their respective search functions based on the hidden input value.

The problem is that the hidden input value is also included in the search query which results in displaying no results. So, I want to exclude this hidden input field from search query. So please help me out. 
Here is the code for search forms.

```
<form class="form-inline" id="searchPropertyForm" role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url($search_submit); ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="sort" id="sort" value="newest" />
            <div class="form-group hidden-xs adv property-search">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle cat">
                        <span class="dropdown-label"><?php esc_html_e('Property Name', 'reales'); ?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
                        <li class="active"><input type="radio" name="search_name" value="0" checked="checked"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><?php esc_html_e('Property Name', 'reales'); ?></a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_name" value="The Golf Residence at Al Hamra Village"><a href="javascript:void(0);">The Golf Residence at Al Hamra Village</a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_name" value="The Duplex at Al Hamra Village"><a href="javascript:void(0);">The Duplex at Al Hamra Village</a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_name" value="‎Townhouses at Al Hamra Village"><a href="javascript:void(0);">‎Townhouses at Al Hamra Village</a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_name" value="The Villas at Al Hamra Village"><a href="javascript:void(0);">The Villas at Al Hamra Village</a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_name" value="The Marina Residence at Al Hamra Village"><a href="javascript:void(0);">The Marina Residence at Al Hamra Village</a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_name" value="The Royal Breeze Residence"><a href="javascript:void(0);">The Royal Breeze Residence</a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_name" value="The Bab Al Bahr Residence"><a href="javascript:void(0);">The Bab Al Bahr Residence</a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_name" value="Bayti Townhomes"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bayti Townhomes</a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_name" value="Bayti Premium"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bayti Premium</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group hidden-xs adv">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle cat">
                        <span class="dropdown-label"><?php esc_html_e('Category', 'reales'); ?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
                        <li class="active"><input type="radio" name="search_p_cat" value="0" checked="checked"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><?php esc_html_e('Category', 'reales'); ?></a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_p_cat" value="Residence"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Residence</a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_p_cat" value="Town House"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Town House</a></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="search_p_cat" value="Villas"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Villas</a></li>                      
                    </ul>
            </div>                                                                                  
            <div class="form-group hidden-xs left-btn">
                <input type="hidden" name="search-type" value="explore" />
                <input type="submit" id="searchPropertySubmit" class="btn button-search" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Search Now', 'reales'); ?>">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-o btn-white pull-right visible-xs" id="advanced"><?php esc_html_e('Advanced Search', 'reales'); ?> <span class="fa fa-angle-up"></span></a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is the code of search page.

```
$form_type = isset($_GET['search-type']);
if($form_type == 'explore') { 
if( !function_exists('reales_search_properties') ): 
function reales_search_properties() {
    $search_id = isset($_GET['search_id']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_id']) : '';
    $search_name = isset($_GET['search_name']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_name']) : '';
    $search_country = isset($_GET['search_country']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_country']) : '';
    $search_state = isset($_GET['search_state']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_state']) : '';
    $search_city = isset($_GET['search_city']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_city']) : '';
    $search_category = isset($_GET['search_category']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_category']) : '';
    $search_type = isset($_GET['search_type']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_type']) : '';
    $search_min_price = isset($_GET['search_min_price']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_min_price']) : '';
    $search_max_price = isset($_GET['search_max_price']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_max_price']) : '';
    $search_bedrooms = isset($_GET['search_bedrooms']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_bedrooms']) : '';
    $search_bathrooms = isset($_GET['search_bathrooms']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_bathrooms']) : '';
    $search_neighborhood = isset($_GET['search_neighborhood']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_neighborhood']) : '';
    $search_p_cat = isset($_GET['search_p_cat']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_p_cat']) : '';
    $search_p_type = isset($_GET['search_p_type']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_p_type']) : '';
    $search_min_area = isset($_GET['search_min_area']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_min_area']) : '';
    $search_max_area = isset($_GET['search_max_area']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_max_area']) : '';
    $search_projects = isset($_GET['search_projects']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_projects']) : '';
    $reales_appearance_settings = get_option('reales_appearance_settings');
    $posts_per_page_setting = isset($reales_appearance_settings['reales_properties_per_page_field']) ? $reales_appearance_settings['reales_properties_per_page_field'] : '';
    $posts_per_page = $posts_per_page_setting != '' ? $posts_per_page_setting : 10;
    $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['sort']) : 'newest';

    global $paged;

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'property_category' => 'explore'
    );

    if($sort == 'newest') {
        $args['meta_key'] = 'property_featured';
        $args['orderby'] = array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC');
    } else if($sort == 'price_lo') {
        $args['meta_key'] = 'property_price';
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    } else if($sort == 'price_hi') {
        $args['meta_key'] = 'property_price';
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    } else if($sort == 'bedrooms') {
        $args['meta_key'] = 'property_bedrooms';
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    } else if($sort == 'bathrooms') {
        $args['meta_key'] = 'property_bathrooms';
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    } else if($sort == 'area') {
        $args['meta_key'] = 'property_area';
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    }

    if($search_id != '') {
        $args['p'] = $search_id;
    }

    if($search_category != '0' && $search_type != '0') {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'property_category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $search_category,
                'operator'  => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'property_type_category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $search_type,
                'operator'  => 'IN'
            ),
        );
    } else if($search_category != '0') {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'property_category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $search_category,
                'operator'  => 'IN'
            ),
        );
    } else if($search_type != '0') {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'property_type_category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $search_type,
                'operator'  => 'IN'
            ),
        );
    }

    $args['meta_query'] = array('relation' => 'OR');

    if($search_country != '') {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_country',
            'value'   => $search_country,
        ));
    }

    if($search_state != '') {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_state',
            'value'   => $search_state,
        ));
    }

    if($search_name != '') {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_name',
            'value'   => $search_name,
            'compare' => '='
        ));
    }

    if($search_city != '') {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_city',
            'value'   => $search_city,
        ));
    }

    if($search_min_price != '' && $search_min_price != '' && is_numeric($search_min_price) && is_numeric($search_max_price)) {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_price',
            'value'   => array($search_min_price, $search_max_price),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ));
    } else if($search_min_price != '' && is_numeric($search_min_price)) {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_price',
            'value'   => $search_min_price,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ));
    } else if($search_max_price != '' && is_numeric($search_max_price)) {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_price',
            'value'   => $search_max_price,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ));
    }

    if($search_bedrooms != '' && $search_bedrooms != 0) {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_bedrooms',
            'value'   => $search_bedrooms,
            'compare' => '='
            /*'type' => 'NUMERIC'*/
        ));
    }

    if($search_bathrooms != '' && $search_bathrooms != 0) {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_bathrooms',
            'value'   => $search_bathrooms,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ));
    }

    if($search_p_cat != '') {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_cat',
            'value'   => $search_p_cat,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ));
    }

    if($search_p_type != '') {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_cat_type',
            'value'   => $search_p_type,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ));
    }

    if($search_neighborhood != '') {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_neighborhood',
            'value'   => $search_neighborhood,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ));
    }

     if($search_projects != '') {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_project',
            'value'   => $search_projects,
            'compare' => '='
        ));
    } 

    if($search_min_area != '' && $search_min_area != '' && is_numeric($search_min_area) && is_numeric($search_max_area)) {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_area',
            'value'   => array($search_min_area, $search_max_area),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ));
    } else if($search_min_area != '' && is_numeric($search_min_area)) {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_area',
            'value'   => $search_min_area,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ));
    } else if($search_max_area != '' && is_numeric($search_max_area)) {
        array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
            'key'     => 'property_area',
            'value'   => $search_max_area,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ));
    }

    $reales_amenities_settings = get_option('reales_amenities_settings');
    $amenities_list = array();
    $amenities = $reales_amenities_settings['reales_amenities_field'];
    $amenities_list = explode(',', $amenities);

    if($amenities != '') {
        foreach($amenities_list as $key => $value) {
            $post_var_name = str_replace(' ', '_', trim($value));

            $input_name = reales_substr45(sanitize_title($post_var_name));
            $input_name = sanitize_key($input_name);
            if (isset($_GET[$input_name]) && esc_html($_GET[$input_name]) == 1) {
                array_push($args['meta_query'], array(
                    'key'     => $input_name,
                    'value'   => 1
                ));
            }
        }
    }

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $query;
}
endif;
if( !function_exists('reales_get_search_link') ): 
function reales_get_search_link() {
    $pages = get_pages(array(
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'property-search-results.php'
    ));

    if($pages) {
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $search_submit = get_permalink($page->ID);
        }
    } else {
        $search_submit = '';
    }

    return $search_submit;
}
endif;
}
```

Comment: `$form_type = isset($_GET['search-type']);` I don't think you want to set `$form_type` to the value of `isset()` as that functions returns true or false.